# Azure B2C - OIDC redirects to Reset Password Flow instead of signing a user in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have an application that utilizes AzureB2C.  The application also has links to partner websites that signs in a user via OIDC.  We have the following scenario:

1. User goes to the website and the website redirects to AzureB2C Sign in page.
2. The user chooses to Reset his password and goes through the reset password flow.  After the user resets his password, he is automatically signed in to our application
3. The user then clicks a link that should allow him to SSO in via OIDC
4. Instead of being automatically signed in, the Azure B2C "Reset Password" page is displayed to the user.

As a workaround, the user has to logout and log back in again to be automatically SSO'd in to the partner site.

How do we fix this so that OIDC does not send the user to the Reset Password page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the setup for the “recommended” password reset flow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#self-service-password-reset-recommended

In the `ForgotPassword` technical profile, set `UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement` to `SM-Noop`.

Comment: Hi Jas!  Thanks for fix.  I modified our custom policy and noticed that the user is not redirected to the Rest Password anymore but the Login screen.  Is there a way to automatically SSO the user in?

Comment: The problem here is that none of the steps now enrol the user into SM-AAD as part of the password reset journey. My workaround here is to add one more claim transformation technical profile after the last step in the password reset subjourney, that just does anything you like, but includes SM-AAD as session management technical profile.